# Вызывать событие при нажатой клавише только если включен CapsLock

Tags: jquery

При нажатии клавиш, например `Q`, выполняется определенное событие.

```
$(document).keydown(function(eventObject)
{
    if (eventObject.which == 77)
    {
        // выполнить
    }
    else if (eventObject.which == 81)
    {
        // выполнить
    }
    else if (eventObject.which == 85)
    {
        // выполнить
    }
});
```

События должны выполняться только если включен `CapsLock` и нажата одна из клавиш. Подскажите как привязать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

<input type="password" id="txt" />

<script>
    function isCapsLock(e) {
        var kc = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        var sk = e.shiftKey ? e.shiftKey : ((kc == 16) ? true : false);
        return (((kc >= 65 && kc <= 90) && !sk) || ((kc >= 97 && kc <= 122) && sk));
    }

    $(function () {
        $("#txt").on('keypress', function (e) {
            if (isCapsLock(e)) alert("CapsLock");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, объясните что делают 2 последние строчки в функции `isCapsLock`?  `var sk... и return (...` что-то связано с Shift, но не понимаю что.

Comment: @Plush _"что делают 2 последние строчки в функции isCapsLock?"_ -- если shiftKey нажат, то true сохраняется в sk, иначе проверяется keyCode. если значение равно 16, то в sk сохраняется true, иначе - false. а дальше проверяется kc (т.е. keyCode). где числа - это код клавиш (у каждой клавиши он свой).

Comment: Верно ли я расположил все, в моем случае? [пример!](https://jsfiddle.net/bn2fbLve/)

Comment: @Plush _"Верно ли я расположил все, в моем случае?"_  -- лишний обработчик был. исправил, см. https://jsfiddle.net/atow7rf5/

Comment: `(kc >= 65 && kc <= 90) && !sk)` - клавиши от `A` до `Z`, если не нажат `shiftKey` — это я правильно читаю? или `(kc >= 97 && kc <= 122) && sk)` — а эти клавиши будут приняты только если нажат `shiftKey`? Не понимаю почему именно такая проверка, как в этом `CapsLock` замешан? и для чего вторая проверка куда входят `F-клавиши` и `NumPad` ?

Comment: _" клавиши от A до Z, если не нажат shiftKey — это я правильно читаю?"_ -- надо смотреть/ не помню. код старый. комментов нет. _"почему именно такая проверка, как в этом CapsLock замешан?"_ -- какая-то особенность для работы в разных браузерах